# Can you use multi-threading in Java play framework?

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework, server

It's a simple question. Can you intentionally run processes in separate threads on play framework as you can with a regular Java application. I can't seem to find an answer to this one.

I currently have a Java desktop application that uses a CPU intensive machine learning utility written in C for finding features in images. With regular Java on a desktop, I can run several instances of the utility at once, each in its own thread, making the image process much faster. On a server with 128 logical cores it would me a mater of seconds instead of minutes. I'd like to redesign my desktop system to allow it to access the resources of a big server. Right now I'm trying to figure out the best way to do that and Play is one option I'm examining -- essentially putting the system on a web page.

Comment: you cannot run processes in threads. You can invoke them from a thread. It is more like invoking a command through Java runtime or ProcessBuilder. If you are simply considering to process a computation breaking into into multiple threads or use a distributed system to process it

Comment: I split the image into tiles, and run the C utility on each tile. So, for example, I might split an image 8x8, and run 64 instances of the C program, one on each tile.

Comment: nice then spawning the action into thread will be simple. You basically create a new Action Object through constructor and then simply execute the run.  This brings to system and memory limitations. I will suggest that you read this nice thread http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97615/what-can-multiple-threads-do-that-a-single-thread-cannot

Comment: also such kind of multi-threaded processing requires a lot of thread/process handling optimizations at system/OS level. Making it a complex problem :D

Answer (score 0):

> Can you intentionally run processes in separate threads on play framework as you can with a regular Java application

According to [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ThreadPools) in section "Using other thread pools", there is no problem creating your own thread pool or using a java executor pool. You also have some options to use the Play thread pool, but it will require tuning.